# Display admob banner in linearlayout

Tags: android, admob, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to display an admob banner in my listactivity but I'm running into problems. I followed the admob quickstart tutorial on the google developers website which uses relativelayout whilst I'm using linearlayout. I've tried tweaking my main xml according to previous answers on SO with varied results, sometimes the app stops/closes on launch and other times the listactivity remains blank. My original xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null" />

<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

With that, the app runs fine but logcat says there's not enough space to display the ad, and when I move the adview above the listview the apps stops on launch. I've tried a different implementation with relativelayout as follows but this causes the app to close on launch as well

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<LinearLayout
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null" />

<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To request for the ad

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Logcat for ads is

```
03-27 12:24:38.697: W/Ads(2094): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 480x0 dp.
03-27 12:24:38.847: I/Ads(2094): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
03-27 12:24:38.887: I/Ads(2094): Ad finished loading.
03-27 12:24:38.887: W/Ads(2094): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 480x0 dp.
03-27 12:24:38.897: W/Ads(2094): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 480x0 dp.
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Post logcat for the error, also for the logcat message _not enough space_ check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786242/admob-not-working-in-app/28800670#28800670) but you are having a `ListView` which can take any amount of space, depending on the initial set of items, at the same time you are having a `WebView` which can take any amount of space when its done loading, at the same time you are displaying and _50dp_ `addView` no mobile device screen can take that sir, so maybe consider a `ScrollView` which means no `ListView` or create a static height viewgroup and tweak them.

Comment: I've added the logcat. The solution provided below solves my problem though, but introduces a new one altogether

Comment: sir like i said in my earlier comment your screen is not long enough to host all those views to its max length.. and about the logcat i was referring to the crashing of your app, because the not showing error that answer in the post i directed you to solves it.. In short you have 0dp as to having 50dp, get it Sir? also if you did use the solution below, make the height match_parent or make it to a static height..

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout_weight`, try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
     android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've done it like and the banner ad is visible. But now there's a blank white space in the listactivity above the banner ad that's about the same size as the banner, and in my webactivity there's a blank white space that takes the upper half of the screen